# Enviar Mails en VB.Net con cifrado SSL TLS 1.2

Tags: vb.net, email, ssl, tls

Desarrollé una aplicación hace un tiempo, que envía por mail las facturas electrónicas que genera. La misma esta desarrollada en Visual Basic .Net (Framework 4.5) y a dos clientes les dejó de enviar los mails porque el hosting donde tienen registrado sus dominios deshabilitó los puertos no seguros (587 en este caso) y dice que el problema se debe a que la aplicación no es compatible con los últimos niveles de cifrado SSL TLS 1.2. Y esto provoca que al intentar conectarse no logren la conexión con el servidor a traves del puerto SMTP SSL. Los clientes que siguen utilizando el puerto no seguro 587 siguen enviando sin problemas, pero al utilizar el puerto 465 y conexión segura SSL deja de funcionar.
El código que se esta utilizando es el siguiente:

```
 Dim _Mensaje As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
 Dim _SMTP As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

    'CONFIGURACIÓN DEL STMP
    _SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("miMail@dominio.com.ar", "miPassword")
    _SMTP.Host = "smtp.dominio.com.ar"
    _SMTP.Port = 465
    _SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    _SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = False

    ' CONFIGURACION DEL MENSAJE
    _Mensaje.To.Add("mailDestino@dominio.com.ar") 'Cuenta de Correo al que se le quiere enviar el e-mail
    _Mensaje.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("miMail@dominio.com.ar", "miNombre", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) 'Quien lo envía
    _Mensaje.Subject = "Asunto" 'Asunto del e-mail
    _Mensaje.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 'Codificacion
    _Mensaje.Body = "Mensaje" 'contenido del mail
    _Mensaje.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    _Mensaje.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal
    _Mensaje.IsBodyHtml = True
    _Mensaje.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "miMail@dominio.com.ar")

    'ENVIO
    _SMTP.Send(_Mensaje)
```

Como debería hacer para que la aplicación sea compatible con el cifrado SSL TLS 1.2 o cual podría ser la solución para que vuelva a enviar los mails sin problemas?